# How can I update global packages in Yarn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I tried some possible CLI commands but none seem to actually update the packages installed with `yarn global add`.

`yarn global upgrade` & `yarn upgrade global` both don't work correctly. Is there a way of upgrading global packages?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install / update ?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

As [webjay says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022750/5353461), you simply:

```
yarn global upgrade
```

in `yarn` version 1.2.1 onwards.

For earlier versions:

```
(cd ~/.config/yarn/global && yarn upgrade)
```

#### Checking and repairing

Sadly, there is currently no `yarn global check`.

You can run `yarn global add --force` to reinstall all packages.

To `check` global packages, you can  treat `~/.config/yarn/global/` like a local package, since:

- `~/.config/yarn/global/package.json` has dependencies for all global packages
- `~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules` contains all the global packages.

**Check all global packages, and reinstall only if an error is found:**

```
$ (cd ~/.config/yarn/global && yarn check || yarn install --force)
```

Comment: with "yarn global upgrade --latest" complained about Outdated lockfile, I had to enter the ~/.config/yarn/global directory and execute "yarn install". only after that I was able to run yarn global upgrade command again.

Answer (score 42):

Using `yarn global add <package>@latest` will upgrade a specific package if that is what you are trying to do.

**Update**

The recently added `yarn global upgrade` upgrades all packages. This did not exist at the time of the original answer.

Comment: To upgrade a single package both `yarn global add <package>` and `yarn global upgrade <package>` works today (but the question asks how to upgrade all global packages, not only one of them).

Comment: Yep that's why I was explicit about what it currently supports. 

Comment: is there something like "ncu -g" to check for updates?

Answer (score 6):

There has been an issue created for this already at  https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/776

Answer (score 6):

Note that per [yarnpkg/yarn #5001](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5001), `yarn global upgrade foo` does not *always* upgrade a package to the latest version, even with the `--latest` flag.

For example, if you have `foo` v12.0.1 installed and v13.0.0 is available, this would not upgrade to v13.0.0 because `yarn global upgrade` currently does not go past major bumps in semver by default (see discussion in above issue for more).

Running `yarn global add foo` *does* upgrade the currently installed version to the latest even if there is a semver major version bump between the currently installed version and the latest version.

I believe that `yarn global upgrade-interactive` would allow one to upgrade past major version bumps as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `yarn global upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error when attempting to upgrade. This started occurring after installing [yarn 2](https://yarnpkg.com).

I was trying to upgrade my globally installed yarn packages via:

```
yarn global upgrade
```

Apparently `yarn global` has been [replaced](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/migration#use-yarn-dlx-instead-of-yarn-global) with `yarn dlx`, however `yarn dlx` [does not do the same](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/821) thing as `yarn global`. How confusing :/.

The trick for me was to temporarily downgrade my installation via:

```
yarn set version classic
```

Now I can run the upgrade command.

After that, I updated again via:

```
yarn set version berry
```